# Page number of a PdfPCell?

Tags: itext

Is it possible to determine which page number a PdfPCell lands on?

Of course a table cell could split across more than one page, so would be happy to know page number of top or bottom of cell.

Ultimately i would like to know the page number and bounds of cells for a 2nd rendering pass after closing the document. Rectangular bounds are easy to determine via PdfPCellEvent's. But i'm having trouble with the page number(s).

iText 5.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rectangular bounds are easy to determine via PdfPCellEvent's. But i'm having trouble with the page number(s).

A `PdfPCellEvent` indeed is the way to go, and during the cell event method invocation you merely have to retrieve the current `PdfWriter.PageNumber` value, e.g. like this:

```c#
public class CellEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    public CellEvent(PdfWriter writer, String name)
    {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cell {0} on page {1} at {2}, {3} - {4}x{5}", name, writer.PageNumber, position.Bottom, position.Left, position.Width, position.Height);
    }

    PdfWriter writer;
    String name;
}
```

Used like this:

```c#
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"Table-CellLayoutInformation.pdf", FileMode.Create))
using (Document document = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
    document.Open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.WidthPercentage = 90;
    table.SplitRows = true;
    table.SplitLate = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.CellEvent = new CellEvent(writer, i.ToString());
        cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."));
        cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."));
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }

    document.Add(table);
}
```

I get the output

```
Cell 0 on page 1 at 514, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 1 on page 1 at 222, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 2 on page 1 at 36, 62.14999 - 470.7x186
Cell 2 on page 2 at 694, 62.14999 - 470.7x112
Cell 3 on page 2 at 402, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 4 on page 2 at 110, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 5 on page 2 at 36, 62.14999 - 470.7x74
Cell 5 on page 3 at 568, 62.14999 - 470.7x238
Cell 6 on page 3 at 276, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 7 on page 3 at 36, 62.14999 - 470.7x240
Cell 7 on page 4 at 748, 62.14999 - 470.7x58
Cell 8 on page 4 at 456, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 9 on page 4 at 164, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 10 on page 4 at 36, 62.14999 - 470.7x128
Cell 10 on page 5 at 622, 62.14999 - 470.7x184
Cell 11 on page 5 at 330, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 12 on page 5 at 38, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 13 on page 6 at 514, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 14 on page 6 at 222, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 15 on page 6 at 36, 62.14999 - 470.7x186
Cell 15 on page 7 at 694, 62.14999 - 470.7x112
Cell 16 on page 7 at 402, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 17 on page 7 at 110, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
Cell 18 on page 7 at 36, 62.14999 - 470.7x74
Cell 18 on page 8 at 568, 62.14999 - 470.7x238
Cell 19 on page 8 at 276, 62.14999 - 470.7x292
```

---

The event listener code above obviously assumes that you indeed draw the table by adding it to the matching `Document`. If you draw a table by using `PdfPTable.WriteSelectedRows` on some arbitrary `PdfContentByte`, the data are likely to be incorrect.

*Code tested with iText 5.5.14-SNAPSHOT.*

Comment: Aha! passing the writer to the cell event. nice one... thanks.